# Charts how to find local bounds of a zoomed chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I have been using chartjs with plugin chartjs-plugin-zoom and I couldn't find a way to get local min and max values of x,y axis. While I zooming in how can I get these bounds.
[image]

For example, I know the max and min values of y however I need the max of y for the data shown on the screen instantly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can get the min and max from the scale itself from the chart object you get as a parameter on the zoom callback like so:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      zoom: {
        zoom: {
          onZoom: ({
            chart
          }) => {
            const xMin = chart.scales.x.getLabelForValue(chart.scales.x.min);
            const xMax = chart.scales.x.getLabelForValue(chart.scales.x.max);
            const yMin = chart.scales.y.min;
            const yMax = chart.scales.y.max;

            console.log(xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax)
          },
          wheel: {
            enabled: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@1.2.1/dist/chartjs-plugin-zoom.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure 100% what you are asking here. I think you are asking if there is a way to get the scale min and max while scrolling? If you are asking that then you can use `chart.getInitialScaleBounds()` in the onZoom or onZoomComplete callback functions. However, if you are asking for a way to get the max scale of the current viewport after zoom... I do not think this is possible after having a good read of the docs and GitHub tickets.

https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/guide/developers.html#chart-getinitialscalebounds-record-string-min-number-max-number

https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/discussions/586

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, we can get the min and max of `x` values on the screen but can not get for the `y` value directly. We should iterate every `x` values to get max/min of `y` between the screen interval. So my code is something like :

```
const { data } = chart.data.datasets[0];
var xMin = 0;
var xMax = data.length;
// I set yMin as yMax to get yMin while iterating over x values
var yMin = chart.scales.y.max;
var yMax = 0;
xMin = chart.scales.x.min;
xMax = chart.scales.x.max;
              
for (let i = xMin; i < xMax; i++) {
  let y = data[i];
  yMin = Math.min(y, yMin);
  yMax = Math.max(y, yMax);
}
```

So I can get the min/max of `y` between leftmost and rightmost pixels of the chart area.

Comment: You can just get then directly as shown in my answer